# Android: How to add button and a custom view

Tags: android, button, view

I use the following View to draw a bitmap and move it around.

```
public class DrawView extends View {
  private ColorBall ball;
  public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    ball = new ColorBall(context,R.drawable.bol_groen, points);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {       
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), null);
  }

  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {        
    switch (event.getAction()) { 
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
               // do stuff...
  }
}
```

In the starting Activity, the layout is set using `setContentView(new DrawView(this));`

I want add a button to the screen and when I click on the button, I want a new bitmap to be added. How do I add a button to this screen?

**EDIT:** This is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<Button android:text="Button" 
    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
<com.example.DrawView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set activity's layout from xml. Put there button and your custom view (you can make it GONE if you don't want it to be visible).

But before making it you should have one more constructor for your view

```
public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
   super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   setFocusable(true);
   ball = new ColorBall(context,R.drawable.bol_groen, points);
}
```

Comment: @rohith I think layout is ok. I have never made my custom view without overriden onMeasure method. Try to use Log in draw method to know actual size of your view and coordinates of the drawn Bitmap.

Comment: Thanks. Got it working. Can you also please tell me how I could add a bitmap on click of the button.

Comment: you should setOnclickListener for your Button. There you can set visibility of the custom view as VISIBLE/GONE. Or you can pass Bitmap you want to draw to your View and invalidate it.